# Change MCC and MNC in Xcode simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I use XCode 4, I want to know if it's possible to change operator MCC and MNC in Simulator and get them when debug when I write the following :

```
    CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
    CTCarrier *carrier = [netInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
    NSString *mcc = [carrier mobileCountryCode];
    NSString *mnc = [carrier mobileNetworkCode];
    NSLog(@"MCC is%@",mcc);
    NSLog(@"MNC is%@",mnc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, In simulator it is not possible to get the mcc and mnc.